# How to change the color of a collada model?

Tags: javascript, collada, worldwind

I try to visualize a self-derived collada model for a web application with WorldWind.
My model is supposed to dynamically change the color.

Here is the link to my [model](https://github.com/scrox/data/blob/master/my_model.dae) which is supposed to change color.
Here are links to other models with color, a [Porsche](https://github.com/scrox/data/blob/master/porsche.dae) and a [satellite](https://github.com/scrox/data/blob/master/satellite.dae). They are well rendered.

Here is my html code:

```
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<canvas id="globe">
  Your browser does not support HTML5
</canvas>
<script src="https://files.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/artifactory/web/0.9.0/worldwind.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Here is my css code:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

and finaly my javascript code:

```
var wwd = new WorldWind.WorldWindow("globe");
wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.BMNGLandsatLayer());
wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.AtmosphereLayer());
wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.CoordinatesDisplayLayer(wwd));

var renderableLayer = new WorldWind.RenderableLayer();
wwd.addLayer(renderableLayer);

var stuff = {};
stuff.ambient = new Float32Array([1, 1, 1, 1]);
stuff.diffuse = new Float32Array([0.66, 0.58, 0.40, 1]);
stuff.emission = new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 1]);
stuff.id = "stuff";
stuff.reflectivity = 0.100;
stuff.shininess = 20;
stuff.specular = new Float32Array([0.33,0.33,0.33,1]);
stuff.techniqueType = "phong";
stuff.transparency = 0;
stuff.transparent = new Float32Array([1,1,1,1]);

var position = new WorldWind.Position(10, -5, 600000);
var colladaLoader = new WorldWind.ColladaLoader(position);
var modelAddress = "my_model.dae";
colladaLoader.load(modelAddress, function (model) {
    model.scale = 500;
    model.materials.stuff = stuff;
    model.meshes['aachen-mesh'].buffers[0].material = "stuff";
    renderableLayer.addRenderable(model);
  });


var position2 = new WorldWind.Position(10, -5, 300000);
var colladaLoader2 = new WorldWind.ColladaLoader(position2);
var modelAddress2 = "porsche.dae";
colladaLoader2.load(modelAddress2, function (model2) {
    model2.scale = 500;
    renderableLayer.addRenderable(model2);
  });


var position3 = new WorldWind.Position(10, -4, 400000);
var colladaLoader3 = new WorldWind.ColladaLoader(position3);
var modelAddress3 = "satellite.dae";
colladaLoader3.load(modelAddress3, function (model3) {
    model3.scale = 500;
    renderableLayer.addRenderable(model3);
    wwd.goTo(new WorldWind.Position(10, -5, 750000));   
  });
```

I try to change the color with these lines:

```
model.materials.stuff = stuff;
model.meshes['aachen-mesh'].buffers[0].material = "stuff";
```

I believe that it could be done with some texture coordinates (UVs). But I am not sure if that is true and if so, how such texture coordinates should be defined or what they feature. I just want uniform colors, nothing fancy.
I am not considerably attached to WorldWind. Alternatives are welcome, as long as it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many children your collada model has.
You could try something like this:

```
this.yourMesh.children[0].material.color = hexToRgbTreeJs('#000000');
```

Helper:

```
const hexToRgbTreeJs = (hex) => {
  const result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);

  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16) / 255,
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16) / 255,
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16) / 255
  } : null;
}
```

I'm using threejs to load the dae file.

Here is a demo changing one sofa child to black: https://codepen.io/iondrimba/pen/mZYLxq?editors=0010

Comment: I grant you the correct answer. Although not complete, it inspired me to solve my problem. Those three lines do the magic: `model.materials.stuff = stuff;
    model.meshes['aachen-mesh'].buffers[0].material = "stuff";
    model.nodes[2].materials = [{id: "stuff",symbol: "stuff"}];`